# Cronjob based on columns in the database

Tags: mysql, hyperlink, cron, get, jobs

I have a database like this. It is required to login to xxx.com/index.php?from=<(romname)&to=(toname) link every 1 minute. I was thinking of doing it with Cronjob but there could be thousands of links. How can I do this automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Elaborate on your problem. It is not well defined. Do you have access to the database? Or just over the http request? You could probably make a scraper (in some random language of your choice) to incorporate a logic to the request. Why do you have to make this every 1 minute? If you want to get the stock quotation there are better ways to do this.

EDIT: Definitely cronjob is not for that. Cronjob is to start a specific job on your server like "start the backup" on something. If you want to populate a database with some **scraper** data over the website, you should use a software (like I mention before) to do that.

Comment: I print the data on a website to the database. These data should be instant. It doesn't have to be 1 minute. The lower the better. Let me explain it this way;
When I enter xxx.com/index.php?from=(romname)&to=(toname) it updates the column in the database. I have access to the database. Let me update all the data one by one according to the columns in this table. But I have to do this automatically.

Comment: If you have access to the database and the application why would you expose a Rest API public? You could simply write a program that executes a while loop getting all the data. Remember, php is a language like any other. Doesn’t have to be called via a webserver IF is not needed to render a webpage.

Comment: I have not made the Rest API public. I save the data from the Rest API to the database. Data is updated when the address I specified is logged in. I want to automate this.